# high cpu usage for uploading with tornado and nginx

Tags: python, python-3.x, nginx, file-upload, tornado

I am dealing with lots of files(100m to 10g), I used nginx with proxy_request_buffering enabled and implemented chunked upload.

while that would work, I plan to disable proxy_request_buffering and process files in tornado using stream_request_body rather than nginx.

Tornado working sample code:

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import RequestHandler, stream_request_body, Application
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer


@stream_request_body
class Upload(RequestHandler):

    def data_received(self, chunk):
        pass

    def post(self):
        self.finish(b'Done')
        return None


io_loop = IOLoop.current()

app = Application([
    (r'/upload', Upload),
], chunk_size=104857600, max_body_size=10737418240)

http_server = HTTPServer(app, chunk_size=104857600, max_body_size=10737418240, xheaders=True)
http_server.listen(8888)

while True:
    try:
        io_loop.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        io_loop.stop()
```

nginx sample config:

```
worker_processes auto; # 1 per cpu core
worker_rlimit_nofile 800000;
events {
    worker_connections 2048;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
    accept_mutex off;
}
http {
    upstream up {
        server 127.0.0.1:8888;
    }

    client_max_body_size      10G;
    proxy_request_buffering   off;
    proxy_send_lowat          3000;

    server {
        listen                80 default_server;
        listen                [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        access_log off;
        location /upload {try_files    $uri @proxy_upload;}
        location @proxy_upload {
            proxy_redirect          off;
            proxy_pass              http://up;
        }
    }
}
```

the sample codes here does exactly what I want, except, even though I do nothing in data_received method, cpu is always around 50% for only one file(one upload process)

How should I use tornado to avoid such a high CPU usage ?

Should I change configurations to fix this ?if yes, what configurations ? Is it Linux related ?

tornado is not capable of doing this good enough ? what framework is out there for this task then ?

And for completeness, the cpu I used for test is Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1276 v3 @ 3.60GHz

Thanks

Comment: FYI: For a 1.1GB file, data_received called 96168 times